# Connection Error in Socket.io in Native Android

Tags: android, websocket, socket.io, serversocket

I was creating a application using `socket.io` in native android application to communicate with `websockets Tester`. I have tested it using a online WebSocketServer , but each time when trying to check the connection  in android device, 'Connection Error` is Logged.

`Error` : `io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: websocket error`
`java.net.ProtocolException: Expected HTTP 101 response but was '404 Not Found'`

onlineTestingPortal link :https://www.piesocket.com/websocket-tester

SocketServerCode:

```
package com.example.appsocket;


import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;
import io.socket.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket;

public class SocketServer {

    private Socket mSocket;

    private static SocketServer lbInstance = new SocketServer();

    public static SocketServer getInstance() {
        return lbInstance;
    }


    public  void callSocketServer(){

        try {
            IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
            options.transports = new String[]{ WebSocket.NAME};

            mSocket = IO.socket("wss://demo.piesocket.com/v3/channel_123?api_key=VCXCEuvhGcBDP7XhiJJUDvR1e1D3eiVjgZ9VRiaV&notify_self",options);

            mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    System.out.println("Connection Error");
                }
            });
            mSocket.connect();

            mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {

                    System.out.println("SocketServer: connected call back" + args[0].toString());
                    mSocket.emit("YOUR_TOPIC", "YOUR_DATA_VALUE");


                }
            });
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception is : " + e);
        }

    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       SocketServer.getInstance().callSocketServer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because of using socket.io library, you don't need socket.io.

In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34132300/14741947), the correct way to connect to ws protocol is mentioned

Comment: why cant we use socket.io ?? can you comment on that?

Comment: your question was solved by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60626303/14741947)

Comment: So we don't have to use any library for communicating with ws and http protocol?

Comment: The answer to this question depends on the project you are doing. ws is only a protocol for real-time connection. If you want to add other options to ws or you want to take responsibility for its security, you can not use it in socket.io event. These things are taken care of by yourself and you only need to use it. To use socket.io, you must use the libraries that are made by the manufacturer for the server and client side.

Comment: I have used the official library from socket.io. does that support everything?  https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/

Comment: What library is your server written with?

Comment: @ Ali Azmoodeh -  currently I'm having a window services.  I have to send and recieve messages throught port , whic can be done through socket communication.

Comment: So there is no need to use socket.io in this case

Comment: can we implement it using socket .io also? Is that possible?

Comment: You can use the socket.io library only if the server side is written with the socket.io library

Comment: So the solution which you have posted ,will it work to send and receive messages to my windows services without thinking on what's written in  windows services?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: can you confirm if the this is the latest version for webSockerClient  `    implementation "org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.9"`

Comment: I have no idea how to fix your problem at the moment

Comment: The solutions is working now. can you confirm the latest version for websocket for Android?

Comment: Currently, I have not used the latest version, but there is no problem

Comment: okay. Let me implement it and verify.

Comment: I'm getting this error onCloseunknown scheme: http.