# app uses websockets but wont connect to server

Tags: android, websocket

I used code I got from this stackoverflow post [What is a simple way to implement a websocket client in Android? Is the following example correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131718/what-is-a-simple-way-to-implement-a-websocket-client-in-android-is-the-followin).

However it won't connect to the NodeJs web backend I have running on my local network. I know the server works because the web application also serves a web page which interacts with the backend via Web Sockets. That works. The following code gives me an exception saying the web socket isn't connected to the server. The address is definately correct as I copied it from the working web frontend. Using a WebView I have checked the application is configured to be able to access the network.

I have also tried a known working Web Socket server on the internet. It won't connect to that either.

```
package com.example.accentag4;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebSocketClient mWebSocketClient ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        try {
            connectWebSocket();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            //Setting the title manually
            alert.setTitle("AlertDialogExample");
            alert.show();
        }
    }
    private void connectWebSocket() {
        URI uri;

        try {
            uri = new URI("wss://alfred.local:883/");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
                TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messages);
                textView.setText(textView.getText() + "\n" + "opening");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String s) {
                final String message = s;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messages);
                        textView.setText(textView.getText() + "\n" + message);

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messages);
                textView.setText(textView.getText() + "\n" + e.getStackTrace());
            }
        };
        mWebSocketClient.connect();
        mWebSocketClient.send("?");
    }
}
```

manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AccentaG4"
    tools:targetApi="31" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```